# How to cache doctrine "findOneBy()" query with cache id and cache lifetime option in Symfony 2.4?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I am working on the symfony 2.5 project with doctrine 2.4.

I want to cache query result with cache id and cache time, so I can delete the cache result, whenever needed though admin.

I am able to cache the query result with "createQueryBuilder()" option.

Example:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('some_table')
                    ->select('some_table')
                    ->where('some_table.deleted_date IS NULL')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->useResultCache(true)
                    ->setResultCacheLifetime(120) //Query Cache lifetime
                    ->setResultCacheId($queryCacheId) //Query Cache Id
                    ->getResult();
```

But I am not able to find the similar way to chache query result for "findOneBy()" option.

Example:

```
$this->findOneBy(array('some_field'=>$some_value));
```

I am looking some proper solution, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/RIeH8ZkKyEY/HnR7h2p0lCQJ

As Ocramius says, you nedd to override this method into repo, if you want to take advantage of caching operations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try it and will ask you more if needed.

Comment: This is how I override "findOneBy" function in repository class 

public function findOneBy(array $criteria_array)
{
  $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')->select('b');
  foreach($criteria_array as $fieldName=>$criteria) {
   $query->andWhere("b.$fieldName = :$fieldName");
   $query->setParameter("$fieldName", $criteria);
  }
  return $query->getQuery()
   ->useResultCache(true)
   ->setResultCacheLifetime(120)
   ->setResultCacheId($queryCacheId)
   ->getResult();
}
Please review and correct me.  
Do I need to override "find*" function in all repository whenever I need to cache result?

Comment: Yes, you need to override every function you need. I trust in Ocramius answer as he's one of Doctrine2 devel ;)

Comment: Got your point. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you put your point as answer? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redefine every findBy* or findOneBy* function into custom repository: this is the only way as doctrine2 default behaviour doesn't take into account this situation.
Is up to you, unfortunately.

Also Ocramius (a Doctrine2 devel) say it here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/RIeH8ZkKyEY/HnR7h2p0lCQJ

Answer (score 2):

Make a common function for this.

```
 $repo->findOneByYourSufff($yourStuff, $yourRepoClass);
```

Followed by your common function :

```
 public function findOneByYourSufff($yourStuff, $yourRepoClass) {


         $q = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('x.*')
                ->from($yourRepoClass, 'x');

                foreach($yourStuff as $fieldKey => $wh) {
                    $q->andWhere("b.$fieldKey = :fieldName");
                    $q->setParameter("fieldName", $wh);
                }

          $q->useResultCache(true)
                ->setResultCacheLifetime(120) //Query Cache lifetime
                ->setResultCacheId($queryCacheId) //Query Cache Id
                ->getSingleResult();

    return $q

 }
```

Comment: This isn't a solution: `$yourStuff` could be an array, how do you handle this case?

Comment: you can put 
->where('x.yourStuff = ?', $yourStuff)
in loop.
prepare your array in your logic function.

Comment: First, is not that "easy" (you should use `andWhere()` [in your loop]), Second your answer didn't highlight that so, to me, is not a good answer. Please update it

Comment: No, It doesn't seems. What `andWhere()` is? I mean, you should use this `andWhere()` into your loop function, after a `where()` call.

Comment: Sufiyan Malek, your way also helped me to come to my final solution. 
Thanks to you as well.

Comment: @DonCallisto : You can use `andWhere()` even when you use it for the first time, there is no need to use `where()` function first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could cache results from a single repository for the functions:

- `findOneBy(['foo' => 'bar'])`
- `findOneByFoo('bar')`
- `findOneBy(['bar' => 'foo', 'foo' => 'bar')`
- etc...

It overrides the `EntityRepository::FindOneBy` function.  It follows the same signature so there is no need to update the invoking code.  All `FindOneBy%` type calls will pass through our implementation of `findOneBy`.

```
<?php
/**
* MyObject Repo    
*/

namespace MyLib\Entity\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MyObjectRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    const CACHE_KEY = 'my_object';
    const ALIAS = 'my_object';

    /**
     * Override - use cache.
     *
     * @param array $criteria
     * @param array|null $orderBy
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder(self::ALIAS);
        foreach($criteria as $field => $value) {
            $queryBuilder->andWhere(self::ALIAS . ".{$field} = :{$field}")->setParameter($field, $value);
        }
        if (is_array($orderBy)) {
            foreach ($orderBy as $field => $dir) {
                $queryBuilder->addOrderBy($field, $dir);
            }
        }
        $queryBuilder->setMaxResults(1);

        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();

        $query->useResultCache(true, 3600, self::CACHE_KEY);

        $result = $query->getResult();

        if ($result) return reset($result);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Depending how you hydrate the entities may make more 
     * sense to use cache layer at findAll
     *
     * @param void
     * @return array The entities.
     */
    public function findAll()
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('select v from \OAS\Entity\MyObject v');

        $query->useResultCache(true, 3600, self::CACHE_KEY);

        $result = $query->getResult();

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function invalidateCache()
    {
        //this would depend on your cache implementation...
        $container = \Zend_Registry::get('doctrine');

        $cache = $container->getCacheInstance();

        $cache->delete(self::CACHE_KEY);
    }
}
```

This could be done in a more OOP fashion of course, extending an intermediary class, if you wanted to say have a property on the repository which simply turned the cache on or off.  You could extend a similar approach for other repository operations functions.

Comment: Incorrect implementation. You will have one cache for all queries. `findOneBy(['name' => 'foo'], ['name' => 'asc']) === findOneBy(['title' => 'foo'], ['title' => 'desc']) === findAll()`

Comment: @ghost404 If I understand what you are saying you are wrong.  Doctrine second level cache has awareness of the query.  See `$querykey` derived from hash of query object in the abstract. Pretty sure at least.  I've got code doing similar for years in production now.